# Vue.js Show value as price but keep it as int

Tags: javascript, focus, vue.js

I have a vue component called "formatted-number", it receives an int value (1234) and changes it currently to a string ("12.34"), so that it is showed as an price (with "," or "." depending on the country) in a textfield.

I would like to keep the value as an int and just show it as a price, so that our users can edit the "string-price" but it also updates the int value in the background.

Do someone have a clue how I can manage this?

Here is the current code:

```
Vue.component('formattedNumber', {
    props: ['value', 'abs'],
    template: '<input type="text" :value="value" autocomplete="off" @blur="updateNumber($event.target.value)" ref="input">',
    mounted: function () {
        this.updateNumber(this.value / 100);
    },
    methods: {
        separators: function () {
            var comparer = new Intl.NumberFormat(navigator.language).format(10000 / 3);

            return {
                thousandSeparator: comparer[1],
                decimalSeparator: comparer[5]
            };
        },
        unformat: function (number) {
            var separators = this.separators();

            var result = number
                .toLocaleString(navigator.language)
                .replace(separators.thousandSeparator, '')
                .replace(/[^\d.,-]/g, '')
                .replace(separators.decimalSeparator, '.');

            return this.abs ? Math.abs(Number(result)) : this.Number(result);
        },
        updateNumber: function (value) {
            this.$emit('input', new Intl.NumberFormat(
                navigator.language,
                {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}).format(this.unformat(value)
            ));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm a little busy but this should get you pretty close: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/xxuda425/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a filter: [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Filters).

Filters only change html output and leave the value intact.

Comment: +1. A filter will work, but you could also use a computed to return the value. My understanding is that behind the scenes computeds have some kind of caching so they can sometimes be more efficient.